# How to add ViewHolder for a GrideView list?

Tags: java, android, android-viewholder

I'm trying to write a `ViewHolder` for this `GridView` list but I'm getting an error every time.
Can you tell me how to make a right ViewHolder for this gridView list?

my code:

```
  public static String[] stringArray = {"IRAN","Uganda",
"Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States Minor Outlying Islands",};

public int[] imageArray = {R.drawable.iran,R.drawable.united_states,R.drawable.iran,R.drawable.russia,
R.drawable.iran,R.drawable.united_states,R.drawable.iran,R.drawable.uk,
R.drawable.iran,R.drawable.united_states  };

public CountryImageAdapter(Context mContext) {this.mContext = mContext;}

@Override
public int getCount() {return imageArray.length;}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {return imageArray[position];}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {return 0;}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {View v;

LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample_gridlayout, null);
v.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.country_text);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivGallery);

textView.setText(stringArray[position]);
imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);

return v;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create a customViewHolder class which extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder and you should find your views there:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.country_text);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivGallery);
```

and you should put these lines:

```
textView.setText(stringArray[position]);
imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);
```

in onBindViewHolder function.